# hostapd: Blacklist devices

Tags: ubuntu, blacklist, hostapd

Is it possible to blacklist specific device (according to their mac address or something similar) on my access point?

I just used a basic configuration, ips are assigned by a dhcp servers on another maschine.

The Access points consists of a laptop equipt with an atheros atk5 network adapter and is configured with hostapd.

Comment: At least define what kind of access point you are talking about.